# is there any way to create a menu bar using glut?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glut

I have tried using pop up menus and wanted to know if there is any way to create a menu bar using glut which would then be customized to give a couple of sub menus

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following lines in your main after displaying the object you want a menu for.

```
glutCreateMenu(menu);  
glutAddMenuEntry("Option 1",1);  
glutAddMenuEntry("Option 2",2);  
glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
```

And add a user defined function called menu

```
void menu(int id) 
{  
   switch(id)      
   {  
      case1: Option1_func();  
      break;  

       case 2: Option2_func();
       break;

     }
  }
```